# Сортировка данных SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, сортировка, дата

0

Имеется БД в MS SQL Server, Таблица WorkitemsCache содержит жизненный цикл талона (тикета), который разработчик доводил до логического завершения. Имею следующие столбцы, по которым нужно сортировать (как мне кажется): ChangeDateMsk - столбец, который отображает время действия работы с талоном (обновил, закрыл, закомитил, перевел на кого-либо и т.д.), TicketId - столбец, который отражает номер талона. Что нужно: отсортировать значения таким образом, чтобы в выводе был весь жизненный цикл умещенный в одной строке без дублирующий значений в столбце TicketId, пример:
[image]

Результат, который хочу получить: Осуществить выборку всех столбцов, отсортировав их по позициям TicketId и ChangeDateMsk, где к номеру талона (столбец TicketId) будет относится только одна позиция с номером,
которая будет являться родительской.
К примеру, есть тикет 260331 (TicketId) (на скриншоте) их 5 значений, родительским тикетом в данном случае является тикет, который создан раньше всех по дате (ChangeDateMsk) т.е в случае тикета с номером 260331 родительским будет являться талон с датой 2020-10-02 13:37:47
Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы, если нужна дополнительная информация все могу предоставить

Comment: Вы покажите желаемый результат-то... А вообще - группировка и [STRING_AGG](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/e825319250f582e7b71973de7691b0e6 Необходимо выполнить запрос, который отсеит не нужные значения, как по ссылке на скриншоте, т.е запрос, который бы вернул бы все первоначальные тикеты

Comment: Т.е. для каждого TicketId надо вернуть только одну запись - с минимальным ChangeDateMsk?

Comment: Да, все верно, извиняюсь за неправильные формулировки (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TicketId ORDER BY ChangeDateMsk) rn
              FROM WorkitemsCache )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я разработчик на c# (автотесты) с sql плоховато очень, я неделю голову ломал себе, еще раз спасибо!